# Cannot install Guest Additions on CentOS virtualbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos

Windows 8.1 host, have previously successfully created a Ubuntu virtualbox on it. Now I wanted a CentOS box.
Choose Redhat 64 bit and created a virtualbox. Downloaded an iso called CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-DVD.iso and installed. 
Before doing anything else, I followed the exact instructions on this site: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/ 
The first error message I obtain is http_:*/*/imgur.com/0fIqfa7 *

```
Building the main Guest Additions module                   [FAILED]
```

Looking in vboxadd-install.log, it says http_:*/*/imgur.com/CxtZ1au *

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: (...)
```

and it refers to /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.3.12/build/make.log, where I read https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCKOU.jpg

```
'struct mm_struct' has no member named 'numa_next_reset'
```

Now I'm clueless. Does anyone have a clue how to solve this problem?

(*sorry, I'm not allowed to post more than two links)

Answer (score 1):

i don't remember the exact same errors, but please make sure you have following packages installed in your guest centos by running:

```
yum install -y kernel kernel-headers kernel-devel kernel-firmware make gcc gcc-c++ libgcc
```

vbox needs development tools installed for building the guest additions

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. Actually I searched some more and finally found a mention of a known bug that causes this problem - will update when I get it to work!